# WordPress: switch meta_query orderby in the frontoffice

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by, custom-post-type

Was looking for a while for a solution, but couldn't find one. So my question is, I have this code that sets posts order by default its DATE:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type'=>'paibcresume',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'paged' => $paged,
  'meta_query' => array(),
  'tax_query' => array(),
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'meta_key' => '',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
```

I need some kind  of a switch on the website, so user can pick how to order posts, for example it could be date to order by date, or modified to order by date of modification, or it could be a custom meta_key. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check below url

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'meta_key' => 'price' ) );

Comment: Yeah, I already did that like half an hour ago, but how to make a switch (filter) thing, so a user could change it on the website?